# Side by Side minipages don't write the text below

Tags: enumerate, minipage, xepersian

I need something like this shape:
[image]

in Xepersian.
I used `minipage` and `enumerate` but I couldn't get the correct result.
Actually, I couldn't write `امضا` in bottom of the left `minipage`.
I would appreciate if you upload a code to do this. My Code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=0.8in,bottom=1in,right=0.8in,left=0.8in,headheight=65pt]{geometry}

%\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
%backend=biber, 
natbib=true,
style=numeric,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}

%\makeatletter
%\define@key{blx@lbx}{fromjapanese}{\blx@defstring{fromjapanese}{#1}}
%\define@key{blx@lbx}{langjapanese}{\blx@defstring{langjapanese}{#1}}
%\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{roundbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{B Zar} 
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\centering\tikz{ \node  [draw, fill=gray!10, rounded corners=4pt]{\setRTL\parbox{\textwidth}{#1}};}}


\addbibresource{Refrences.bib}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{}
%\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{}{}{} 



\bibliography{Refrences.bib}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\bullet$}
\begin{document}

\noindent


\hfill

\begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
    \centering
    \raggedright
    \small
    \textbf{شماره: } \\
    \textbf{تاریخ:\today}
\end{minipage} 
\\[1mm]

\hrule height1pt
\noindent

%\roundbox{%
%   \parbox{1\linewidth}{
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*},start=1]





        \item \textbf{کلمات کلیدی فارسی:}

        \textbf{کلمات کلیدی انگلیسی:} 
        \item \textbf{مدت زمان اجرا پایان نامه  :} 

        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            به ماه:
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
            تاریخ شروع :
        \end{minipage}  

        \item \textbf{مراحل اجرا پایان نامه}




        \item \textbf{روش پژوهش و تکنیک ها اجرائی}
        \item \textbf{سابقه علمی و فهرست منابع}

        \item \textbf{وسایل مورد نیاز و تجهیزات} 
        \item \textbf{اعتبار اجرای پایان نامه و نحوه تامین آن}(ریالی و ارزی)


        \item \textbf{نظریه استاد راهنما}

        \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
            .
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{.1\linewidth}
            \textbf{امضا}
        \end{minipage}

        \item \textbf{نظریه مسئول تحصیلات تکمیلی دانشکده}

        \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
            .
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{.1\linewidth}
        \textbf{امضا}
        \end{minipage}
        \item \textbf{رئیس دانشکده}

        \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
            .
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{.1\linewidth}
            \textbf{امضا}
        \end{minipage}

        \item \textbf{تعهدنامه دانشجو}

        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \end{minipage}

        \begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
            %\centering
            .
        \end{minipage}  
        \begin{minipage}{0.1\linewidth}
            %\centering
            \textbf{امضا}
        \end{minipage}

        \item \textbf{نظریه شورای تحصیلات تکمیلی دانشگاه}

        \begin{minipage}{.9\linewidth}
            .
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{.1\linewidth}
            \textbf{امضا}
        \end{minipage}

        \item \textbf{سایر توضیحات}





\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried so far. Please also clarify the need for either `minipage` or `enumerate` environments.

Comment: There is a high probability that people downvote your question. Give your working code so people can easily give a solution modifying your code.

Comment: @alhelal @Mico Sorry , I didn't check my post for few days.I edited the post. as you see I cann't make frame around the `enumerate`